# Java Struts2 Action map issue

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to struts2 and trying to learn very awesome struts2 framework.

But I am stucked to a very critical issue as mentioned:
`There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name Struts2Example1.`

I am using IntelliJ IDE and the content of my **web.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Struts2Example2</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <!--<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>-->
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">


<struts>
</struts>
```

Can anybody help me to get rid of this error.

Thanks

Comment: Well the error says it all. You don't have any action mapped for the namespace you try to reach. You might want to provide more information on what you try to do exactly.

Comment: Read the tutorials http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tutorials.html

Comment: Your error message is a good sign.  It means that struts2 is trying to handle your request.  So your web.xml is good.  What is missing is what tells struts2 what "Struts2Example1" action is.  You can use struts.xml to do this or the struts2-conventions-plugin, for learning it is better to start with the xml but the later is far easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to learn a new framework is to download some sample applications from the struts2 official website, check them how they are configured and how they are running
[Download Example Applications:](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts231-SNAPSHOT)

And what you have described in your query it seems there is some mapping issues with your config file
more over the struts.xml file you have provided do not include any mapping entry, so its always better to provide complete details